# Text transformation - model training in Python

Tags: python, transformation, unsupervised-learning

I have a source data file (region, product,month-year, Sales amount) and want to transform this data by modifying the 'region' ID.

#### Source Data

```
US, prius, 10-2017, 100000.00
US, leaf, 10-2017, 25000.00
UK, prius, 10-2017, 65000.00
```

#### Target Data

```
NA-US, prius, 10-2017, 100000.00    
NA-US, leaf, 10-2017, 25000.00
EU-UK, prius, 10-2017, 65000.00
```

I am transforming US -> NA-US and UK -> EU-UK

I do not want to maintain a mapping table, what would be the approach to train the model and transform the IDs? Assuming there will not be new 'region' IDs in source nor target.

Comment: Can you show us how you're storing the data?
Is it a class object, an array, a list, a csv...?

Comment: It's a csv file

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution would be to use regular expressions.

```
your_csv_data.replace("^US,", "NA-US,")
your_csv_data.replace("^UK,", "EU-UK,")
```

If you only need to match these two cases, a regex will do the job simply enough.

Comment: Is it possible to train a model? In the actual dataset there will be many records to modify. Replace is like maintaining a mapping table.

Comment: Program Synthesis looks promising, https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/machine-learning/preview/data-prep-split-column-by-example.md